Export KML polygon with symbols in QGIS
I have a simple polygon shapefile with some attributes.  I symbolize the polygon shades based on a single attribute.  I want to export this with the symbols so I can open directly in Google Earth, QGIS or ArcGIS Pro with the symbols.
I have tried the save features as KML and the symbology export: "feature symbology" and "symbol layer symbology" but in both cases I just get the polygon boundary with no fill.
I tried the "KML tools" plugin export KMZ, with and without the "Export style for single, categorized, and graduated symbols" checked on or off.  I still don't get a fill.  I tried setting a single simple fill on the polygon (not what I want but it is a test) and still the KMZ had no embedded symbol.
Using QGIS 3.34


Shapefile format doesn't support the concept of shared symbology. It's possible that a SpatialLite data layer might get you closer, but one dataset, common symbology is not common.

The data is originally oracle geodatabase, the data does not contain symbology, that is true but qgis maps and qlrs do.  That is sort of the point of KML, export the data with the symbols, or else, I can just keep it as a shapefile.  I can do this in arcgis (arcmap and pro) it simply applies the symbols as it writes the kml or kmz.
